# Lazyloading unable to find module

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm new to nativescript - just installed it, so everything shoud be up-to-date. I've been trying to get lazy loading to work by following the guide on the nativescript website:

https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/lazy-loading#implementing-lazy-loading-in-nativescript

I've followed the guide to the letter, only adding an empty service and providing a component with a template string. On running in the android emulator, I get the following exception:

```
 JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "feature/feature.module", relative to: app/tns_modules/
JS:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
JS:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
JS:     com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_view_31_32_TouchListenerImpl.onTouch(Object_view_31_32_TouchListenerImpl.java:18)
JS:     android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11721)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(...
Executing before-prepare hook from C:\apps\stoiccompanion\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Successfully transferred app.routing.js.
Refreshing application...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.StoicCompanion on device emulator-5554.
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

I've tried varous forms of path including ~/, / ./ etc, but still no joy.

I've also tried to use `tns update` in case something is out of date. Looking around online, I can see a few similar issues on their github, which has uncovered a couple of leads (ensure there are no uppercase filenames etc), but not have any luck.

If it matters, I'm using Windows 10.

Are there any common errors I should be looking out for, or are there any tools or logs I can investigate to try and get more details?

Here is my app.route

```
// app/app.routing.ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { ItemsComponent } from "./item/items.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item/item-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/items", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent },
    { path: "feature", loadChildren: "~/feature/feature.module#FeatureModule" }, // lazy loaded module
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My app directory structure is:

- src

  - app

    - feature

      - feature.component.ts
      - feature.module.ts
      - feature.service.ts
      - feature.routing.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - app.routing.ts
  - etc

**Edit**

Wrote a big edit, then found a typo in the filenames. Fixed that and it would appear to be working now. However, I still cant use `loadChildren:` in the app level router using a relative path `./app/feature/...` works, but `~/feature/...` doesnt.

Updating to ~/feature results in the following exception:

```
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "~/feature/feature.module", relative to: /app/
JS:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
JS:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
JS:     com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_view_31_32_TouchListenerImpl.onTouch(Object_view_31_32_TouchListenerImpl.java:18)
JS:     android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11721)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
JS:     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup...
```

My tsconfig file has the following entry:

```
"paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "src/*"
            ],
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
```

I found the following link, which seems to imply I should update the ~/ alias to point to /app, which I tried, but still had the same problem. I also tried to update with ./src/app

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/372

Comment: Which template you started your project with? Just wondering why you have placed modules and routing outside app folder, all your source code usually gets inside app folder. Obviously it's flexible with Angular web, I'm unsure about NativeScript Angular.

Comment: I just followed along with their tutorial and used the cli to create the app (tns create my-app --ng). I believe that uses their blank / hello world template

Comment: Just to add - the app.routing is in the src/app directory, and the module resides in src/app/feature

Comment: May I know what is your CLI version (`tns --version`)? Also did you try `./app/feature...`?

Comment: tns version is 4.2.4, just tried ./app/feature/. Looks to be hitting the module now, but there are other issues. It's late here, so going to stop for the evening. Will update question with more details

Comment: update with the new errors may be we can help

Comment: updated with more information, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I dabbled around, and it worked by adding `./app/` string inside loadChildren, like so
    Inside `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent

},
{
    path: "collection",
    loadChildren: "./app/collection/collection.module#CollectionModule"
},
{
    path: "product",
    loadChildren: "./app/product/product.module#ProductModule"
}
];
```

and its working if routed to a lazy loaded module from a component, such as from `home.component.html`

```
<Button text="home works!" class="btn btn-primary" [nsRouterLink]="['/collection']"></Button>
```

and it's working if you make a lazy loaded module as a first route.
But all of this would also depend on the project structure, normally in angular you have a structure, where you put the modules inside the app folder, like so

[image]